# How to insert data in azure easy table?

Tags: azure, xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services

I want to insert the data in a specific column of azure easy table with xamarin  forms.i already insert the data in a row but some fields are empty and these can be fill later by the user when user want to update the record.
for example  there is a table which name is
**USER(User-id,UserName,Email,Password,Mobile-No)** 
 user enter all data except MobileNo and it may or may be entered first time but may enter later.if they enter mobile number later then how I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all , All CRUD are operated on the object in Azure easy table .If you create this record at the first time, You could insert this record to Azure easy table. If user want to add the mobile number in the next time, you could query this record, then delete the old data, put the new record to the table.

You could refer to following link.
https://officialdoniald.azurewebsites.net/2017/02/24/xamarin-forms-azure-easy-table-accsess/

If you want to know more basic knowledge, you can refer to the link below
https://blog.xamarin.com/getting-started-azure-mobile-apps-easy-tables/

Comment: is it possible to update the record with out deleting the old data.

Comment: public string Id
        {    get { return id; }
            set { id = value;
            }}
        public string Username
        {
            get { return username; }
            set
            {
                username = value;}}     
        public string Password
        {
            get { return password; }
            set
            {
                password = value;
            }}  first i insert the record (await azureServices.InsertAsync(User);) then next time i have to update like this (await azureServices.UpdatAsync(User);)  am i right??